# Inline editing for HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, inline-editing

I have following jquery function that displays table.

```
$(function() {
    $("#table-contact > tbody").html("");
    $.ajax({
            "url" : '/Contact/' + id,
             type: 'GET',
             success: function(data) {
             $.each(data.details, function(k, v) {
                  var dataArr = new Array();
                  dataArr.push('<label class="id">'+ v.id + '</label>');
                  dataArr.push('<select data-val=' + item.course + ' ><option>Science</option><option>Economics</option><option>Literature</option><option>Maths</option><option selected>' + item.course + '</option></select>');   // Here I am getting 2 values for selected option
                  dataArr.push('<input type="text" name="category">' + v.catg + ' </disabled>');
                  dataArr.push('<label class="name">'+ v.name + '</label>');
                  $('#table_contact > tbody:first').append('<tr><td>' + dataArr.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
              });

         },
    };
```

I need to do inline editing for 2nd and third column - upon clicking these fields, it will display a dropdown box to select. And on clicking 'save', it needs to save all the data from the table.

[image]

Comment: You have label in second and third column that makes it non-editable!

Comment: Do I have to make it as a text field or something?

Comment: yes, something like that! make is non editable by default, and once you click it make it editable!

Comment: use it like this `<input type="text" name="lname" disabled/>`

Comment: I think something went wrong in my explaination it should be like this  `<input type="text" name="lname" disabled> + xyz+ </input>` ; But, anyways it doesn't make much difference now as virrote's solution worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks MarmiK.  I need some more help as a continuation of this. Could you please help me in that?  -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111454/retrieve-only-the-fields-that-are-modified-from-html-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [my jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18897055/301303) as example, it doesn't take care of populating the table, just edit/save it:  http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/wgtf6y24/

Also, I would rather style select as simple input box when state is not `:active` and style it as normal select for `:active` and `:focus` so your users will be able to *tab* through your table. (see example of such styling in snipped below)

We initially did table like that, where you need to click on table cell to edit it, it is pain in the neck for users.

```js
var t = $('table'), inputs = t.find('input, select'), b = $('button'), ta = $('#save')

t.on('change', 'input, select', (e) => {
      $el = $(e.target)
      $el.data('val', $el.val())
      console.log($el.val())
})

b.on('click', () => {
   var data = []
   inputs.each((i,inp) => data.push($(inp).data()) )
 ta.text(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

```css
input {border : 1px solid #fff;margin:0; font-size:20px; }
input:focus,input:active,input:hover { outline: 1px solid #eee; background-color:#eee; }
select { border: 1px solid #fff; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:20px; border:0; 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
}

table { border : 1px solid #999; border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; }
table td { padding:0; margin:0;border:1px solid #999; }
table th { background-color: #aaa; min-width:20px;border:1px solid #999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="0">
        <th>1</th>
        <td><input disabled type="text" data-row="0" data-col="0" data-val="a" value="a" /></td>
        <td>
<select data-row="0" data-col="1" data-val="yes"><option>yes</option><option>no</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-row="0" data-col="2" data-val="c" value="c" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="1">
        <th>2</th>
        <td><input disabled type="text" data-row="1" data-col="0" data-val="d" value="d" /></td>
        <td><select data-row="1" data-col="1" data-val="no"><option>yes</option><option selected>no</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-val="f" value="f" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="2">
        <th>3</th>
        <td><input disabled type="text" data-row="2" data-col="0" data-val="g" value="g" /></td>
        <td><select data-row="2" data-col="1" data-val="no"><option>yes</option><option selected>no</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-val="i" value="i" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div name="data" id="save" cols="30" rows="10"></div>
<button>Save</button>
```

Comment: Changed code as edited in the question. But seems like  t.on('change', 'select', (e) => {
        alert('hi');
    }) ;
this is not working

Comment: @Futuregeek click run code snippet - change drop down value then save. it works for me. What browser you are trying?

Comment: There is onething I need help - on displaying dropdown - it displays selected value twice - as I am giving like   <select data-val=' + item.course + ' ><option>Science</option><option>Economics</option><option>Literature</option><option>Maths</option><option selected>' + item.course + '</option></select>'    -> if db returns maths - then 2 maths option will be there in dropdown

Comment: @Futuregeek just don't do it. apply selected attribute to the actual value.

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working fine. I need to get the updated rows only - can you help in that?

Comment: you can add some type of dirty checking. for instance add to data fields one `data-original-value` and `data-value` , in the code that you execute on save add check `data['original-value'] !== data['value']`.